# How to display items in a list with a description of what that list item is in c# console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, generic-list

I am trying to display a list sorted in descending order with each item being displayed with a description of what the value of the item is in VS console app. I’m just not sure how to display the description with each item

Eg. output:
Total monthly expenses//description of list item : $1000//item obtained from list and sorted
Home loan repayment: $700
Vehicle Installment: $300

Thank you

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Where are you getting the $$$$ values and description values from?

Comment: Snippet: List<double> list2 = new List<double>();

            //adding to list 2
            list2.Add(result1);
            list2.Add(result2);
            list2.Add(result3);
            list2.Add(result4);

            list2.Sort();
            list2.Reverse();

            foreach (double item in list2 )
            {
                if(item > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n\nDisplaying the expenses in decending order\n: " + item);
                }

            }

Comment: The $ value I retrieved from user input and stored into a list of expenses. For each loops iterate through expenses list to get result values. Result values are sorted by desc and displayed. What I’m trying to display are these results values with with a description telling the user what that value is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see where you are getting the description values from. A better way to do this would be to use Dictionary instead of a List.

```cs
double cost = textbox1.Text; // cost of item
string des = textbox2.Text; //description of item

//below code goes into a event to add each item cost+description
Dictionary<double, string> io = new Dictionary<double, string>();
io.Add(cost, des);

//below code goes into a event to display all items
foreach(KeyValuePair<double, string> val in io.OrderByDescending(i => i.Key)) {
Console.WriteLine("${0},{1}", val.Key, val.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have fetched the data from the database, store the data in a dictionary collection. The key in the key-value pair of the dictionary set is the product description information, and the value is the specific price. You can first extract the value of the key in the dictionary set for sorting, and then extract the value value in the dictionary set according to the value of the key.

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    d.Add("keyboard", 100);
    d.Add("mouse", 80);

    //get key
    var val = d.Keys.ToList();

    //sort
    val.Sort();

   
    foreach (var key in val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
}
```